# How to open iPhone simulator and paired watchOS simulator at the same time?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, watchos

I am learning development for the Apple Watch app paired with the iOS app. I created an iPhone simulator and paired it with a watch simulator. I was going through this tutorial - https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui/creating-a-watchos-app downloaded the project files and opened the Xcode project from the 'Completed' folder.

When I run the app using the iOS scheme and select the paired simulator, I only see the iPhone simulator coming up. If I run the watch target, I only know the watch simulator and no iPhone simulator. I went ahead and unchecked "Supports running without iOS App Installation" from Watch Target -> General -> Deployment target and even after that I am just seeing the watch simulator getting displayed. I want to see both iPhone and watch side by side.

Please let me know how can I do this on Xcode 13.2.1. Below are some pics.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Apple watch tutorial (source - https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui/creating-a-watchos-app)

[image]

Comment: The watch app and the phone app are separate targets.  You need to select a phone simulator with a paired watch and then in Xcode start the watch app and then start the phone app

Comment: Thanks @Paulw11! I was able to set it up the way you mentioned. Any idea if my existing iOS app is created using storyboard which has a tableview within it and that table view uses custom UITableViewCell, then do I need to create the UI again for Watch app? I attached a new image(last image which says "Add the Landmarks List") in my question above which is from Apple Watch tutorial and it is confusing me. It states the iOS UI can be used for Watch too, but I wonder it is true only if iOS app was created using SwiftUI?

Comment: Watch apps do not use UIKit.  You can use SwiftUI or the older WatchKit UI elements.

Answer (score -1):

Open the simulator applications from your macOS applications, use the mouse options menu on the icon in the dock, and select -> device -> watchOS, you can start your paired watch simulator from there.